# How to I take the words out of a matrix of characters and spaces and put them into an array of strings?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, char

I have created an 11 X 11 matrix where the characters of a crossword puzzle can be entered. The sections where letters are not wanted are filled with a space. I am trying to take the matrix and find all the words in it both horizontal and vertical then store them in an array. Any help would be much appreciated as I am fairly new to programming in java! Thank you!

Comment: Could you clarify/edit this question? I see at the end you are using java. Perhaps post some code of what you have with a comment in the code for where you want to do something else. What do you mean by "find all the words in it?" Do you mean check against a dictionary to verify that the input letters are indeed words? Or do you mean check that they are correct given a known set of answers? Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example in 'C', translating to java should be straight forward

The logic is exactly the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void matrixwords(char matrix[11][11])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;
    char str[12];
    /* process each row i using column j */
    k = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 11; ++j) {
        char c = matrix[i][j];
        if (c != ' ') {
            str[k++] = c;
        } else {
            /* found a word in the row */
            if (k != 0) {
                str[k] = '\0'; /* terminate word */
                printf("found a row word %s\n", str);
                k = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    /* don't forget last word in row */
    if (k != 0) {
        str[k] = '\0'; /* terminate word */
        printf("found a row word %s\n", str);
        k = 0;
    }
}
/* process each column j using row i*/
k = 0;
for (j = 0; j < 11; i++) {
    for (i = 0; i < 11; ++j) {
        char c = matrix[i][j];
        if (c != ' ') {
            str[k++] = c;
        } else {
            /* found a word in the row */
            if (k != 0) {
                str[k] = '\0'; /* terminate word */
                printf("found a column word %s\n", str);
                k = 0;

            }
        }
    }
    /* don't forget last word in column */
    if (k != 0) {
        str[k] = '\0'; /* terminate word */
        printf("found a column word %s\n", str);
    }
    k = 0;
}
```

}